# Drawbacks to an idling fixed threadpool

Tags: java, multithreading, performance, threadpool

I'm currently in the process of doing various performance improvements in a software. As it is using SWT for it's GUI, I have come across a problem where under certain circumstances a lot of UI elements are created in the Display Thread.
Since the person before me, didn't really take care to do any calculations outside of the Display Thread, the whole software can be unresponsive for several seconds on startup.
I've now isolated the code that needs to be performed in the Display Thread, and I'm now calculating everything else in Runnables that I submit to a fixed Threadpool.
I'm using the pool like this:

```
public abstract class AbstractChartComposite {
private static ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(8);

private List<String> currentlyProcessingChartItems = new ArrayList<>();

protected void doCalculate(constraints){
for (IMERuntimeConstraint c : constraints) {
    if(!currentlyProcessingChartItems.contains(c.getId())){
        currentlyProcessingChartItems.add(c.getId());
        pool.submit(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try{
                  createChartItem(c);
                currentlyProcessingChartItems.remove(c.getId());
                }catch(Throwable e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }
  }
}
}
```

I'm now wondering, if I have any drawbacks to leaving the Threadpool running at idle, once all the UI elements have been created. I cannot really shut it down for garbage collection, because it will be needed again on user Input when a new element needs to be created.
So are there any major drawbacks on leaving a threadpool with no submitted Runnables running?

Comment: Not really. Just takes up some memory. You could have a non-fixed threadpool that can shrink down to zero, too.

Comment: I suggest you show the code used in creating the threadpool.

Comment: @Thilo so you'd suggest probably something like a cached Threadpool? That sounds like a good idea to me.

Comment: Note that you are accessing an `ArrayList` (which is not thread safe) from multiple threads, including modifications. That will surly break some day.

Comment: @Holger thanks, I'll fix that in my code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there are no drawbacks.

The threads won't be actually *running*, they'll be *parked* until a new task is submitted. So it does not affect CPU. Also you say that you will use this pool again, so in your case there's no point of shutting it down and recreating again.

As to the memory - yes, idle threads will consume some amount of memory, but that's not an issue as well, until you have hundreds (thousands?) of threads.

Also, a piece of advice. Do not do premature optimizations. That's the root of all evil. Analyze a problem once you have real performance issues, using special utilities for that and detecting bottlenecks.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. This is not premature though. Our goal is to have our software work for over a week and it has previously always crashed because of memory problems. It also has become quite unresponsive over the years. 10 seconds of freeze during startup is nothing we wanted to tolerate any longer. That's why I'm currently looking into various optimizations with Visual VM, MAT for heapdump analysis and some other tools.

Comment: @Radioo, you're welcome. In this case, tuning the thread pool is not what you really want to do :) Focus on other parts of the system.

Comment: Good Answer. I would add a caution about being sure to shutdown the thread pool when no longer needed, or when the app exits. Otherwise the threads may continue after the program has ended.

Comment: @PavelSmirnov Thanks. I just want to make sure, I don't introduce any new issues while optimizing.

Comment: As a side note, if these idle threads are still a concern, you can easily replace `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(8)` with `new ThreadPoolExecutor(0, 8, 1L, TimeUnit.MINUTES, new LinkedBlockingQueue<Runnable>())`. Then, a thread will get terminated when being idle for at least a minute, but gets recreated when needed. The change is tiny, compared to the implementation of `newFixedThreadPool`. But anyway, the answer is right, eight idle threads do not harm anyone.